# Where is "Read/Write class files" in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I cannot for the life of me find any information about where this moved to in Xcode 4.  In Xcode 3.2, I would simply select my view/whichever object and go to File > Write Class Files... and it would save the classes for me.

This is probably very simple to answer, but the documentation for Xcode 4 reveals nothing about this UI change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just don't do it any more because of the way Xcode 4's integrated Interface Builder functions.

When you are looking at an Interface Builder view, try clicking the button that looks like a little tuxedo - a variant of Apple's annoying (to me, can't explain why) "assistant" icon. You will get a pane of the corresponding source file zooming in. Control-drag from your object to your source file - presto, IBOutlet or IBAction created!

If your IB files are out of sync with source, either go do the "write class files" step in Xcode 3 before switching to 4, or make all the connections again. There is just no need for "read class files" because the xib and source are intimately connected.

See [page 65](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009984-CH6-SW2) of the "[XCode 4 Transition Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)" This document is worth reading in full even if you've been developing for years.

Comment: Is there still no way to do this? I don't use Xcode for building or editing code (I use Waf and Vim). I use it only for creating XIBs. Edit: [this answer seems useful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9168107/142019).