# How to switch window view

Tags: ios, uiwindow

In my app I have one .xib file with three `Window`s. I'm not using Storyboard.
To change the view between `Window`s when pressing a button, I used this code:

```
-(IBAction) SwitchView1 {

    [window setHidden:NO];
    [window1 setHidden:YES];
    [window2 setHidden:YES];
}
```

However I'm having some problems. Is there an alternative for my case?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Yes, window, window1 and window2 are instances of UIWindow

An iOS app has only one UIWindow. It is created at app launch and never changes. Do not do otherwise. It is wrong, foolish, and unnecessary. It is, quite simply, not how iOS programming is done.

See my answer here, for documentation citations:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15909159/341994

Comment: you are correct in your answer, but I seriously think the guy meant `UIView`. `UIWindow` doesn't even respond to `setHidden`

Comment: @Luke Sure it does. UIWindow is a UIView subclass. UIView has `setHidden:`, therefore so does UIWindow; that is what it means to be a subclass.

Comment: Oh my, you are correct again. But still..

Answer (score 1):

Are window, window1, and window2 instances of UIWindow? If so, you can't switch these windows (as there should only one UIWindow instance per app). You can switch views though (instances of UIView). I would also suggest looking at other ways that you can present views on iOS, as setting the hidden property of views is generally not the best approach.

Comment: Yes, window, window1 and window2 are instances of `UIWindow`. So if I want to change view without the hidden property of views must I insert more .xib files into my project?

Comment: There are many, many different ways to switch views. I honestly suggest you just read some beginners guides to iOS development. The Apple programming guides are very helpful. Those will get you going.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect properly the button(IBAction) and the views (IBOutlets) ?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168107/1341626) for more details on how to connect the interface with your code